# How to Store UUID In table using wso2dss3.0.1

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using wso2dss3.0.1 and using POSTGRESSQL database so i have table in my database like

```
        uuid table
    ========================
    column name | datatype
----------------------------------
        uuid    | uuid
       deviceid | bigint
      objectid  | bigint
        message | string
```

So i wish insert the data using wso2dss but its unable to insert and its giving like this errors

```
</soapenv:Text>
   </soapenv:Reason>
   <soapenv:Detail>
      <axis2ns1:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns1="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">DS Fault Message: Error in DS non result invoke.
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: taction_DataService
Location: /taction_DataService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: insertinto_seenuuid_op
Current Params: {uuid=a0eebc999c0b4ef8bb6d6bb9bd380a11, objectid=-1, deviceid=-1}
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "uuid" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 53

</axis2ns1:DataServiceFault>
   </soapenv:Detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Now my issue is my database column type is fix i can't change it how would i send this to database using wso2dss if its possible what type of datatype i could use in DSS query parameter because there is no UUID type is there 
Is it any way to send a UUID through the DSS

Comment: The message tells you to cast it… `CAST(col as uuid)` or (in postgres) `col::uuid`

Comment: insert into seenuuid(CAST(col as uuid),deviceid,objectid) values(?,?,?) i have done like this but giving errror syntax error at CAST

Comment: <query id="Insertinto_SennUUID" useConfig="default">
      <sql>insert into seenuuid(uuid::uuid,deviceid,objectid) values(?,?,?)</sql>
      <param name="uuid" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="deviceid" ordinal="2" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
      <param name="objectid" ordinal="3" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
   </query>

Comment: sorry CAST working boss thanx a ton

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, casting the column to UUID is the way to go.

However, digging deeper, I wonder what wso2dss is doing here.  Normally columns come in as `UNKNOWN` types and are then pulled in as appropriate.   For this to come in as `varchar()`, ws0dss must be specifying that during the query execution.  So it seems like you are then doing something like `"uuid"::varchar()::uuid` which seems to me to be a bit of a problem.

So while you have a workaround, I think that's all this is.  The real question is what to do to get wso2dss to work with custom data types.  I wish I had an answer there, but it may require some custom code, I think.